# Generating random number android

Tags: android, numbers, generator

I'm new to the Android world, I'm doing an application-style Simon.
but I'm stuck, I'm not able to create a code that creates random numbers to match the start button.

Could someone help me please?

thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

Comment: Android is written in Java. If you have basic programming questions that dosen't directly relate to the mobile device or the UI, there's a very good chance you can find the answer on StackOverflow if you search for "Java" rather than "Android".

Answer (score 5):

Try this. Returns an int in the half-open range (0 to 100)

```
Random rand = new Random();
int abcd = rand.nextInt(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Hemanth answer,

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(45 - 28) + 28;
```

This gives a random integer between 28 (inclusive) and 45 (exclusive), one of 28,29,...,43,44.

Answer (score -1):

I would generate a number from 1 to 4, to be inserted in the code part of the start button.

edit the code where I should add

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnStart= (Button)findViewById(R.id.status);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Here I should generate the random code
            // I created the toast to see if it worked
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " start click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    });
```